# Various sized squares grid

Tags: html, css

Is it possible using only html and css to do something like that:

[image: squares]

The other requirement is that, since the divs are generated automatically in list,
they should not be encapsulated in other html element (for instance adding a div for each line is not possible):

the html looks like that:

```
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="big_s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="big_s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
    <div class="s"></div>
```

That means that they are in a form of a list.

I did not find how to do this for now, it seems that using float:left and clear:both is not a solution, neither using display:inline-block

If anyone had an idea how I could do this, that would be great!

Thank you.

Comment: The `div` elements are inevitably enclosed in some HTML element, at least the `body` element. If you mean that you cannot have an element that contains only them, then this is an odd restriction and seems to make things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: You should clarify the part “they are in a form of a list but can be separated by spacers or br or something else” with an example, and you should show your best effort (HTML+CSS) so far.

Comment: I mean I cannot enclose for instance 4 small square in a div to make it a bigger square, or I cannot use a table. That was the meaning of this sentence. I cannot do that because the html is produced automatically on server side and is subject to change at any time.

Comment: How do you expect to style it if it is subject to change at any time? You need to specify the invariants (things that don’t change, describing some pattern) to make this a meaningful question.

Comment: The pattern is that you have a list of divs in a container. The divs represent each a big square or a small one. But the html will always only be a list of divs. The only exception is that I could add some spacer between them if that is useful.

Comment: So there *is* a container? Even though you first wrote “they should not be encapsulated in other html element” and there is no container in the sample markup? And you haven’t described the intended meanings of the class names. But if the pattern is as free as it seems to be, there is little hope of doing the styling with CSS alone, even if we (unrealistically) assumed the availability of things like CSS Grid module. CSS is not a programming language.

Comment: Jukka K. Korpela, I really do not get what you don't understand. It seems to me that you are avoiding the point on purpose here. What I meant obviously by “they should not be encapsulated in other html element” is that I cannot for instance put the five at the top in a div to make a line then the four at the left of the big square in a div to make a square and then the six under etc, etc...

Comment: They are produced by the server in php and are stored in an unidimensional array, so either I do some calculation on server side to encapsulate them in other divs, either I do this in javascript and I want to avoid both of those two cases. I wanted to know if CSS was able to do so naturally and it seems that it is not the case. I didn't think Stackoverflow was meant to ask only question that have answers.

Comment: FWIW, that layout is exceedingly simple with a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the closest you can achieve with exactly the HTML code provided and `float: left` or `overflow: hidden` on `.bs`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GIcAi (just comment out/comment in both lines in the last rule)

You'd have to rely on absolute positioning and very complicated selectors failing at the first modification of HTML code... That's why positioning like Masonry needs JavaScript (because height of elements are nearly always unknown: fonts, zoom, etc WILL vary except with test cases like yours ;) )

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know Masonry. I guess if there is no pure css solution I'll go with javascript and probably this library.

Comment: CSS3 solution like flexible box layout is IE9+ and won't work either. Grid layout would but it's IE10+ only (no Fx, no WebKit) and Windows 8-formerly-known-as-Metro :)